# wp_trash_post is leaking memory

Tags: plugins, memory, optimization

I have a plugin that deletes a list of posts based on their post id.

The code is very simple

```
    foreach ( $post_ids as $post_id ) {
            wp_trash_post( $post_id, true );
        }
    }
```

However I found that after deleting about 200 posts WordPress was running out of memory. So I added a debug statement just before the function call.

```
    foreach ( $post_ids as $post_id ) {
            error_log(number_format(memory_get_usage()));
            wp_trash_post( $post_id, true );
        }
    }
```

After printing the memory usage I found that after each call to the function, the memory usage increases by 1MB. Here is the error_log after enabling.

```
[13-May-2015 07:00:22 UTC] 4,696,680
[13-May-2015 07:00:22 UTC] 5,546,264
[13-May-2015 07:00:22 UTC] 6,357,632
[13-May-2015 07:00:22 UTC] 7,318,472
[13-May-2015 07:00:22 UTC] 8,176,520
[13-May-2015 07:00:23 UTC] 9,230,352
[13-May-2015 07:00:23 UTC] 10,189,496
[13-May-2015 07:00:23 UTC] 11,340,784
[13-May-2015 07:00:23 UTC] 12,293,720
[13-May-2015 07:00:23 UTC] 13,306,000
[13-May-2015 07:00:23 UTC] 14,399,040
[13-May-2015 07:00:23 UTC] 15,200,872
[13-May-2015 07:00:23 UTC] 16,102,872
[13-May-2015 07:00:23 UTC] 17,147,096
[13-May-2015 07:00:23 UTC] 18,045,096
[13-May-2015 07:00:23 UTC] 19,040,560
[13-May-2015 07:00:23 UTC] 19,846,544
[13-May-2015 07:00:23 UTC] 20,707,888
[13-May-2015 07:00:23 UTC] 21,892,520
[13-May-2015 07:00:23 UTC] 22,845,200
[13-May-2015 07:00:23 UTC] 23,846,232
[13-May-2015 07:00:23 UTC] 24,798,752
[13-May-2015 07:00:23 UTC] 25,656,736
[13-May-2015 07:00:23 UTC] 26,426,752
[13-May-2015 07:00:23 UTC] 27,329,552
[13-May-2015 07:00:23 UTC] 28,161,096
[13-May-2015 07:00:23 UTC] 29,125,568
[13-May-2015 07:00:23 UTC] 30,230,144
[13-May-2015 07:00:23 UTC] 31,223,688
[13-May-2015 07:00:23 UTC] 32,339,904
[13-May-2015 07:00:23 UTC] 33,350,272
[13-May-2015 07:00:23 UTC] 34,253,088
[13-May-2015 07:00:23 UTC] 35,057,400
[13-May-2015 07:00:23 UTC] 35,960,944
[13-May-2015 07:00:23 UTC] 36,876,744
[13-May-2015 07:00:23 UTC] 37,921,256
[13-May-2015 07:00:23 UTC] 38,723,616
[13-May-2015 07:00:24 UTC] 39,833,088
[13-May-2015 07:00:24 UTC] 40,857,000
[13-May-2015 07:00:24 UTC] 41,757,760
[13-May-2015 07:00:24 UTC] 42,705,680
[13-May-2015 07:00:24 UTC] 43,607,560
[13-May-2015 07:00:24 UTC] 44,608,680
[13-May-2015 07:00:24 UTC] 45,515,608
[13-May-2015 07:00:24 UTC] 46,533,264
[13-May-2015 07:00:24 UTC] 47,643,224
[13-May-2015 07:00:24 UTC] 48,634,448
[13-May-2015 07:00:24 UTC] 49,852,744
[13-May-2015 07:00:24 UTC] 50,784,032
[13-May-2015 07:00:24 UTC] 51,588,168
[13-May-2015 07:00:24 UTC] 52,495,528
[13-May-2015 07:00:24 UTC] 53,350,008
[13-May-2015 07:00:24 UTC] 54,239,256
[13-May-2015 07:00:24 UTC] 55,054,616
[13-May-2015 07:00:24 UTC] 55,863,480
[13-May-2015 07:00:24 UTC] 56,949,080
[13-May-2015 07:00:24 UTC] 57,869,168
[13-May-2015 07:00:24 UTC] 58,888,280
[13-May-2015 07:00:24 UTC] 59,880,080
[13-May-2015 07:00:24 UTC] 60,627,624
[13-May-2015 07:00:24 UTC] 61,835,984
[13-May-2015 07:00:24 UTC] 62,970,504
[13-May-2015 07:00:24 UTC] 64,010,176
[13-May-2015 07:00:24 UTC] 65,336,904
[13-May-2015 07:00:24 UTC] 66,453,480
[13-May-2015 07:00:24 UTC] 67,569,816
[13-May-2015 07:00:25 UTC] 68,470,776
[13-May-2015 07:00:25 UTC] 69,372,360
[13-May-2015 07:00:25 UTC] 70,278,408
[13-May-2015 07:00:25 UTC] 71,276,536
[13-May-2015 07:00:25 UTC] 72,183,376
[13-May-2015 07:00:25 UTC] 73,018,936
[13-May-2015 07:00:25 UTC] 74,041,176
[13-May-2015 07:00:25 UTC] 74,942,720
[13-May-2015 07:00:25 UTC] 75,943,024
[13-May-2015 07:00:25 UTC] 77,053,696
[13-May-2015 07:00:25 UTC] 77,980,824
[13-May-2015 07:00:25 UTC] 79,391,384
[13-May-2015 07:00:25 UTC] 80,384,816
[13-May-2015 07:00:25 UTC] 81,282,688
[13-May-2015 07:00:25 UTC] 82,489,744
[13-May-2015 07:00:25 UTC] 83,497,296
[13-May-2015 07:00:25 UTC] 84,398,976
[13-May-2015 07:00:25 UTC] 85,804,440
[13-May-2015 07:00:25 UTC] 86,708,912
[13-May-2015 07:00:25 UTC] 87,615,952
[13-May-2015 07:00:25 UTC] 88,746,936
[13-May-2015 07:00:25 UTC] 89,747,000
[13-May-2015 07:00:25 UTC] 90,549,968
[13-May-2015 07:00:25 UTC] 91,726,896
[13-May-2015 07:00:25 UTC] 92,626,080
[13-May-2015 07:00:25 UTC] 94,111,616
[13-May-2015 07:00:25 UTC] 95,205,136
[13-May-2015 07:00:25 UTC] 96,063,704
[13-May-2015 07:00:26 UTC] 97,359,584
[13-May-2015 07:00:26 UTC] 98,461,808
[13-May-2015 07:00:26 UTC] 99,266,808
[13-May-2015 07:00:26 UTC] 100,091,304
[13-May-2015 07:00:26 UTC] 101,100,856
[13-May-2015 07:00:26 UTC] 102,292,768
[13-May-2015 07:00:26 UTC] 103,282,904
[13-May-2015 07:00:26 UTC] 104,216,760
[13-May-2015 07:00:26 UTC] 105,047,576
[13-May-2015 07:00:26 UTC] 105,901,504
[13-May-2015 07:00:26 UTC] 106,920,392
[13-May-2015 07:00:26 UTC] 107,632,128
[13-May-2015 07:00:26 UTC] 109,018,464
[13-May-2015 07:00:26 UTC] 110,057,984
[13-May-2015 07:00:26 UTC] 111,061,800
[13-May-2015 07:00:26 UTC] 111,964,488
[13-May-2015 07:00:26 UTC] 112,885,176
[13-May-2015 07:00:26 UTC] 113,688,680
[13-May-2015 07:00:26 UTC] 114,610,664
[13-May-2015 07:00:26 UTC] 115,509,600
[13-May-2015 07:00:26 UTC] 116,713,664
[13-May-2015 07:00:26 UTC] 117,743,432
[13-May-2015 07:00:26 UTC] 118,645,336
[13-May-2015 07:00:26 UTC] 119,667,128
[13-May-2015 07:00:26 UTC] 120,477,528
[13-May-2015 07:00:26 UTC] 121,516,296
[13-May-2015 07:00:26 UTC] 122,631,928
[13-May-2015 07:00:27 UTC] 123,623,880
[13-May-2015 07:00:27 UTC] 124,643,248
[13-May-2015 07:00:27 UTC] 125,545,872
[13-May-2015 07:00:27 UTC] 126,541,536
[13-May-2015 07:00:27 UTC] 127,443,128
[13-May-2015 07:00:27 UTC] 128,345,432
[13-May-2015 07:00:27 UTC] 129,343,600
[13-May-2015 07:00:27 UTC] 130,247,832
[13-May-2015 07:00:27 UTC] 131,344,736
[13-May-2015 07:00:27 UTC] 132,399,960
[13-May-2015 07:00:27 UTC] 133,296,800
[13-May-2015 07:00:27 UTC] 134,203,000
[13-May-2015 07:00:27 UTC] 135,194,848
[13-May-2015 07:00:27 UTC] 136,326,864
[13-May-2015 07:00:27 UTC] 137,324,992
[13-May-2015 07:00:27 UTC] 138,249,680
[13-May-2015 07:00:27 UTC] 139,185,984
[13-May-2015 07:00:27 UTC] 140,089,488
[13-May-2015 07:00:27 UTC] 141,013,040
[13-May-2015 07:00:27 UTC] 142,028,400
[13-May-2015 07:00:27 UTC] 142,999,944
[13-May-2015 07:00:27 UTC] 143,926,840
[13-May-2015 07:00:27 UTC] 144,829,368
[13-May-2015 07:00:27 UTC] 145,734,256
[13-May-2015 07:00:27 UTC] 146,732,232
[13-May-2015 07:00:28 UTC] 147,892,568
[13-May-2015 07:00:28 UTC] 148,832,824
[13-May-2015 07:00:28 UTC] 149,841,304
[13-May-2015 07:00:28 UTC] 150,756,736
[13-May-2015 07:00:28 UTC] 151,695,136
[13-May-2015 07:00:28 UTC] 152,633,664
[13-May-2015 07:00:28 UTC] 153,672,880
[13-May-2015 07:00:28 UTC] 154,615,160
[13-May-2015 07:00:28 UTC] 155,660,448
[13-May-2015 07:00:28 UTC] 156,657,704
[13-May-2015 07:00:28 UTC] 157,701,944
[13-May-2015 07:00:28 UTC] 158,505,608
[13-May-2015 07:00:28 UTC] 159,432,120
[13-May-2015 07:00:28 UTC] 160,233,904
[13-May-2015 07:00:28 UTC] 161,532,384
[13-May-2015 07:00:28 UTC] 162,429,056
[13-May-2015 07:00:28 UTC] 163,327,088
[13-May-2015 07:00:28 UTC] 164,867,880
[13-May-2015 07:00:28 UTC] 165,670,944
[13-May-2015 07:00:28 UTC] 166,482,768
[13-May-2015 07:00:28 UTC] 167,285,864
[13-May-2015 07:00:28 UTC] 168,395,040
[13-May-2015 07:00:28 UTC] 169,231,424
[13-May-2015 07:00:28 UTC] 170,223,056
[13-May-2015 07:00:28 UTC] 171,224,584
[13-May-2015 07:00:29 UTC] 172,226,816
[13-May-2015 07:00:29 UTC] 173,317,296
[13-May-2015 07:00:29 UTC] 174,043,584
[13-May-2015 07:00:29 UTC] 174,946,848
[13-May-2015 07:00:29 UTC] 176,062,520
[13-May-2015 07:00:29 UTC] 177,061,448
[13-May-2015 07:00:29 UTC] 178,087,840
[13-May-2015 07:00:29 UTC] 179,013,256
[13-May-2015 07:00:29 UTC] 179,918,472
[13-May-2015 07:00:29 UTC] 180,934,784
[13-May-2015 07:00:29 UTC] 182,135,416
[13-May-2015 07:00:29 UTC] 182,938,944
[13-May-2015 07:00:29 UTC] 183,840,320
[13-May-2015 07:00:29 UTC] 184,757,368
[13-May-2015 07:00:29 UTC] 185,757,176
[13-May-2015 07:00:29 UTC] 186,662,832
[13-May-2015 07:00:29 UTC] 187,465,072
[13-May-2015 07:00:29 UTC] 188,379,904
[13-May-2015 07:00:29 UTC] 189,286,456
[13-May-2015 07:00:29 UTC] 190,191,440
[13-May-2015 07:00:29 UTC] 191,096,784
[13-May-2015 07:00:29 UTC] 191,930,512
[13-May-2015 07:00:30 UTC] 192,931,688
[13-May-2015 07:00:30 UTC] 193,835,808
[13-May-2015 07:00:30 UTC] 194,738,520
[13-May-2015 07:00:30 UTC] 195,732,544
[13-May-2015 07:00:30 UTC] 196,534,032
[13-May-2015 07:00:30 UTC] 197,491,112
[13-May-2015 07:00:30 UTC] 198,444,304
[13-May-2015 07:00:30 UTC] 199,346,600
[13-May-2015 07:00:30 UTC] 200,441,920
[13-May-2015 07:00:30 UTC] 201,309,864
[13-May-2015 07:00:30 UTC] 202,501,384
[13-May-2015 07:00:30 UTC] 203,611,752
[13-May-2015 07:00:30 UTC] 204,609,992
[13-May-2015 07:00:30 UTC] 205,507,128
[13-May-2015 07:00:30 UTC] 206,407,672
[13-May-2015 07:00:30 UTC] 207,310,272
[13-May-2015 07:00:30 UTC] 208,383,456
[13-May-2015 07:00:30 UTC] 209,281,520
[13-May-2015 07:00:30 UTC] 210,227,264
[13-May-2015 07:00:30 UTC] 211,233,192
[13-May-2015 07:00:30 UTC] 212,079,232
[13-May-2015 07:00:30 UTC] 213,124,256
[13-May-2015 07:00:31 UTC] 214,022,656
[13-May-2015 07:00:31 UTC] 215,044,896
[13-May-2015 07:00:31 UTC] 216,046,232
[13-May-2015 07:00:31 UTC] 217,137,488
[13-May-2015 07:00:31 UTC] 217,940,952
[13-May-2015 07:00:31 UTC] 218,940,712
[13-May-2015 07:00:31 UTC] 219,748,856
[13-May-2015 07:00:31 UTC] 220,706,072
[13-May-2015 07:00:31 UTC] 221,563,304
[13-May-2015 07:00:31 UTC] 222,564,040
[13-May-2015 07:00:31 UTC] 223,461,952
[13-May-2015 07:00:31 UTC] 224,555,328
[13-May-2015 07:00:31 UTC] 225,545,896
[13-May-2015 07:00:31 UTC] 226,543,472
[13-May-2015 07:00:31 UTC] 227,637,136
[13-May-2015 07:00:31 UTC] 228,468,552
[13-May-2015 07:00:31 UTC] 229,570,920
[13-May-2015 07:00:31 UTC] 230,399,912
[13-May-2015 07:00:31 UTC] 231,066,992
[13-May-2015 07:00:31 UTC] 232,066,920
[13-May-2015 07:00:31 UTC] 232,968,176
[13-May-2015 07:00:31 UTC] 234,187,296
[13-May-2015 07:00:31 UTC] 235,089,256
[13-May-2015 07:00:32 UTC] 235,888,320
[13-May-2015 07:00:32 UTC] 236,796,312
[13-May-2015 07:00:32 UTC] 237,655,048
[13-May-2015 07:00:32 UTC] 238,752,888
[13-May-2015 07:00:32 UTC] 239,705,472
[13-May-2015 07:00:32 UTC] 240,702,624
[13-May-2015 07:00:32 UTC] 241,703,936
[13-May-2015 07:00:32 UTC] 242,607,008
[13-May-2015 07:00:32 UTC] 243,588,640
[13-May-2015 07:00:32 UTC] 244,489,640
[13-May-2015 07:00:32 UTC] 245,592,280
[13-May-2015 07:00:32 UTC] 246,585,120
[13-May-2015 07:00:32 UTC] 247,443,128
[13-May-2015 07:00:32 UTC] 248,434,496
[13-May-2015 07:00:32 UTC] 249,390,544
[13-May-2015 07:00:32 UTC] 250,481,296
[13-May-2015 07:00:32 UTC] 251,671,680
[13-May-2015 07:00:32 UTC] 252,579,680
[13-May-2015 07:00:32 UTC] 253,572,496
[13-May-2015 07:00:32 UTC] 254,675,232
[13-May-2015 07:00:32 UTC] 255,671,560
[13-May-2015 07:00:32 UTC] 256,434,616
[13-May-2015 07:00:32 UTC] 257,237,632
[13-May-2015 07:00:32 UTC] 258,419,168
[13-May-2015 07:00:33 UTC] 259,317,504
[13-May-2015 07:00:33 UTC] 260,241,424
[13-May-2015 07:00:33 UTC] 261,244,648
[13-May-2015 07:00:33 UTC] 262,243,616
[13-May-2015 07:00:33 UTC] 263,046,136
[13-May-2015 07:00:33 UTC] 263,903,784
[13-May-2015 07:00:33 UTC] 265,011,368
[13-May-2015 07:00:33 UTC] 265,951,328
[13-May-2015 07:00:33 UTC] 267,148,208
[13-May-2015 07:00:33 UTC] 268,149,048
[13-May-2015 07:00:33 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 268435456 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 72 bytes) in /srv/www/wordpress-default/wp-includes/formatting.php on line 1765
```

A quick glance at wp_trash_post didn't reveal anything.

Does anyone know why wp_trash_post is leaking memory or if there is any way to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it seems `SAVEQUERIES` is the culprit.

After disabling `SAVEQUERIES` memory usage is down.